# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Line 71

Tags: php, mysql

8th June**

I've updated the code and it now updates the database, if I enter data that is the same it fires back the error below of a duplicate error, is it possible to just come up and say its a duplicate rather than telling me with a big error?

```php
UPDATE clients2 SET id = :id, fullname = :fullname, paypal = :paypal, email = :email, serial_no = :serial_no, toolkitserial = :toolkitserial WHERE id = :id
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '11111-11111-11111-11111' for key 'serial'
```

So the code is almost complete and the only thing left is to fix the duplication errors.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Use an HTML form to edit an entry in the
 * users table.
 *
 */

require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $user =[
      "id"        => $_POST['id'],
      "fullname" => $_POST['fullname'],
      "paypal"  => $_POST['paypal'],
      "email"     => $_POST['email'],
      "serial_no"       => $_POST['serial_no'],
      "toolkitserial"  => $_POST['toolkitserial'],

    ];

    $sql = "UPDATE clients2 
            SET id = :id, 
              fullname = :fullname, 
              paypal = :paypal, 
              email = :email, 
              serial_no = :serial_no, 
              toolkitserial = :toolkitserial

            WHERE id = :id";

  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute($user);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}
$user = array();
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients2 WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();

    $user = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
    exit;
}
?>

<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) : ?>
    <blockquote><?php echo escape($_POST['fullname']); ?> successfully updated.</blockquote>
<?php endif; ?>

<h2>Edit a user</h2>

<form method="post">
    <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($user as $key => $value) : ?>
      <label for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo escape($value); ?>" <?php echo ($key === 'id' ? 'readonly' : null); ?>>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

To be able to edit the database file.

Comment: Maybe here, `UPDATE clients2 SET id = :id`, and `WHERE id = :id` in the same query?  And the next one? You do have actual, working human eyes, yes …?

Comment: It says “Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'” directly in the error message - and you are not able to go [ctrl]+[f] and start typing “where” to locate those places in your script?

Comment: Doesn't show me the info to edit the details. I see the submit button but errors

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: I've updated the client_id on the where.

Comment: Now get Notice: Undefined variable: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() <?php foreach ($user as $key => $value) : ?>

Comment: In which case? When you submitted the form, or when you call the script via GET including an ID parameter? If it is not one of those cases, then there is no variable $user defined at that point in your script.

Comment: @04FS Not quite sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: There are two places in your script where you give $user a value - inside the if branch that checks if $_POST['submit'] is set, and inside the if branch that checks if $_GET['id'] is set. If _neither_ of those is the case, then there simple _is_ no variable $user in the place where you try to foreach over it.

Comment: I've updated the code above, now a new error, fixed the id.

Comment: _“is it possible to just come up and say its a duplicate rather than telling me with a big error?”_ - sure, check the numeric error code, and depending on it output either the original error message, or your own, custom one …

Answer (score 1):

it should be like

```
$sql = "UPDATE clients2 
          SET fullname = :fullname, 
          paypal = :paypal, 
          email = :email, 
          serial_no = :serial_no 
        WHERE client_id = :id";
```

You are using `id` but you have changed it to `client_id`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

<?php foreach ($user as $key => $value) : ?>

Comment: @BeLostTwice **line 47:** `$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients2 WHERE client_id = :id";`                          **line 74:** `<input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo escape($value); ?>" <?php echo ($key === 'client_id' ? 'readonly' : ''); ?>>`

Comment: I've updated the code above with your change as well

Answer (score 1):

The variable $user is undefined.

Put `$user = array();` before the line `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {`

Comment: Does the suggestion above fixed the undefined?

Comment: For your update sql, remove the comma(,) after `toolkitserial = :toolkitserial,` so that it looks like this. `toolkitserial = :toolkitserial WHERE id = :id`

Comment: Hi @Jim.B That fixed the issue but if I enter data that is the same I get the error: UPDATE clients2 SET id = :id, fullname = :fullname, paypal = :paypal, email = :email, serial_no = :serial_no, toolkitserial = :toolkitserial WHERE id = :id
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry - Is there a way to just display duplicate rather than error out?

Comment: Does the `email` column caused the duplicate entry? then remove the UNIQUE index from your table. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update, you need to know `'id'`.

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])) { // not set redirect to ....

$id = $_GET['id']; // if isset
```

then update.

This code does not look good:
If you use OO, use something like `databaseobject.class.php` and put insert, update, delete, find by id, find by sql .....
the use it e.g `static public function find_by_id($id)`.

Comment: Because I am completely new at this I have no idea what you mean with OO or anything you said after that but thank you.

Comment: OO that mean object oriented programming.